# Pre-Select a radio button in a asp.net radiobuttonlist based on a value/text in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, radiobuttonlist

I have a asp:RadioButtonList which gets data from sql-server. The radiobuttonlist is created in a pop-up edit window. 
And since it is an edit window, there should be pre selections so the user can see the existing data which is pre selected radio buttons.

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList4" runat="server"
                     DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3"
                     DataTextField="NAME"
                     RepeatColumns="2">
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

I have tried to put this line of code in my "on_click to open edit window" button but it is not working:

```
RadioButtonList4.Items.FindByValue("some string").Selected = true;
```

I am open to jquery solutions also at this point of time.

Comment: There's no `DataValueField` specified, what exactly are the "values" in `RadioButtonList4.Items`?

Comment: it is dynamic, the items are populated by sqldatasource

Comment: Well, if you don't know what the values are or control where they come from, then `.FindByValue()` is kind of a shot in the dark, isn't it?  What is the data you're using and why do you expect `"some string"` to be in that data?  When you say "it is not working", what *specifically* are you expecting to happen and why?  And what specifically *is* happening?

Answer (score 0):

May be you could try to clear the selection first ,like this :

```
RadioButtonList4.ClearSelection();
RadioButtonList4.Items.FindByValue("some string").Selected = true;
```

But your issue could because of the popup , may be you don't have access to RadioButtonList4 on this event , or someone is preselecting the value.
Also be sure that you have value : some string in your data source.

In general , your approach is the correct one , search for the issue somewhere else